# Slow Shader compile time

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm using three.js/r87. Chrome 60.0.3112.113.

I build 2 meshes, each using a new ShaderMaterial, so that's 2 ShaderMaterials that are created. The vertex shader and fragment shader are the same in both, in fact the materials are identical except that I set `side=THREE.FrontSide` in one case and `side=THREE.BackSide` in the other case. (I'm using the workaround suggested here:https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2476#issuecomment-9076268). So actually they are not totally identical, one vertex shader has `#define FLIP_SIDED` and the other does not. My shaders don't use FLIP_SIDED, so this extra flag is unnecessary.

So this vertex shader gets compiled 2 times, once for each material. But the 2nd time it is compiled it is quite slow - 5 seconds or so each time.

How do I know? By using Chrome performance analyzer. Then I confirmed it by setting a break in the three.js code and putting time statements around the slow statement and having it print out the shader that is slow to compile, e.g.:

```
return function WebGLShader( gl, type, string ) {

    var shader = gl.createShader( type );

    gl.shaderSource( shader, string );
    gl.compileShader( shader );

    var t0 = performance.now();
    if ( gl.getShaderParameter( shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS ) === false ) {

        console.error( 'THREE.WebGLShader: Shader couldn\'t compile.' );

    }
    var t1 = performance.now();
    if ((t1 - t0) > 1000) {
        console.log("------------------Slow compile.----------------");
        console.log(string);
    }
    //  .....etc....
```

}

The shader that gets printed out is the vertex shader, on the SECOND TIME it is compiled. The vertex shader is quite simple:

```
varying vec2 vUv; 
uniform float morphTargetInfluences[ 4 ];
void main()
{
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0 );
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    vUv = uv;
}
```

So I'm looking for advice how to debug this slow compile time. Additionally, answers to any of the following questions would be enlightening:

1 - Why is it the vertex shader that is slow to compile?
2 - Why is it slow the second time it compiles?
3 - Since my shaders don't use FLIP_SIDED, is there a way to not have the flag included in the shader (and thereby avoid an extra compile)?

Any suggestions or pointers would be useful.

Comment: any chance you could create a fiddle?

Comment: @BobWoodley can you please create a fiddle so this question can get some love?

Comment: I encountered the same problem in my new GPU font-effect design project http://fonted.io It's in react so it's the page never unloads but shaders are recompiled quite a lot. Did you find a solution for this?